# timestamp in SQS message can't be converted in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, amazon-sqs, date

I created a DTO to map message came from AWS SES to SQS through SNS but the timestamp converter didn't work properly with `objectMapper` created by spring boot. I tried to map the timestamp with (`ZonedDateTime`/ `LocalDateTime` / `Instant`) and I always get an error

I used these versions 
spring-boot version is 2.2.5
spring-cloud version is Hoxton.SR3
I explicitly specify Jackson version to be 2.9

here is the message

```
{
  "notificationType": "Bounce",
  "bounce": {
    "bounceType": "Permanent",
    "bounceSubType": "Suppressed",
    "bouncedRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": "blacklist@simulator.amazonses.com",
        "action": "failed",
        "status": "5.1.1",
        "diagnosticCode": "Amazon SES has suppressed sending to this address because it has a recent history of bouncing as an invalid address. For more information about how to remove an address from the suppression list, see the Amazon SES Developer Guide: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/remove-from-suppressionlist.html "
      }
    ],
    "timestamp": "2020-03-20T21:00:42.217Z",
    "feedbackId": "01070170f9bf8131-9cbe20b1-7997-4d33-8e02-7e828eb01edc-000000",
    "reportingMTA": "dns; amazonses.com"
  },
  "mail": {
    "timestamp": "2020-03-20T21:00:42.217Z",
    "source": "tester@####.com",
    "sourceArn": "arn:aws:ses:eu-central-1:425905684163:identity/####",
    "sourceIp": "54.239.6.46",
    "sendingAccountId": "425905684163",
    "messageId": "01070170f9bf8091-79e59712-3c2d-424c-9eba-3e221ef336ff-000000",
    "destination": [
      "blacklist@simulator.amazonses.com"
    ],
    "headersTruncated": false,
    "headers": [
      {
        "name": "From",
        "value": "tester@####.com"
      },
      {
        "name": "To",
        "value": "blacklist@simulator.amazonses.com"
      },
      {
        "name": "Subject",
        "value": "lkasnlkaslknaslkn"
      },
      {
        "name": "MIME-Version",
        "value": "1.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "Content-Type",
        "value": "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
      },
      {
        "name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
        "value": "7bit"
      }
    ],
    "commonHeaders": {
      "from": [
        "*****"
      ],
      "to": [
        "blacklist@simulator.amazonses.com"
      ],
      "subject": "lkasnlkaslknaslkn"
    }
  }
}
```

The mapping for the bounce object is

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Bounce {
    private BounceType bounceType;
    private BounceSubType bounceSubType;
    private List<Recipient> bouncedRecipients;
    private ZonedDateTime timestamp;
    private String feedbackId;
    private String remoteMtaIp;
    private String reportingMTA;

    public static enum BounceType {
        Permanent, Transient
    }

    public static enum BounceSubType {
        General, Suppressed
    }

}
```

Comment: [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) can do that.

Comment: @OleV.V. this module already added by spring 2 and later!

Comment: I fixed this by adding my own deserializer

Comment: Please show me your bean configuration of `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` and `QueueMessagingTemplate`

Comment: You added your own deserializer every time you have LocalDateTime field?

Answer (score 0):

jackson-modules-java8 can do that. This works for me:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

    String message = "{ \"timestamp\": \"2020-03-20T21:00:42.217Z\" }";

    Dto obj = mapper.readValue(message, Dto.class);

    System.out.println(obj.getTimestamp());
```

Output is (as you may have expected):

> ```
> 2020-03-20T21:00:42.217Z
> ```

Note that I am explicitly registering the Jackson java.time module on the mapper. If you were to use the mapper for serialization too, you would additionally need:

```
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
```

For the sake of a complete example, The `Dto` class I was using is very simple, just a field with getter and setter:

```
public class Dto {

    private Instant timestamp;

    public Instant getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Instant timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

}
```

I did not try with a field of type `ZonedDateTime` nor `OffsetDateTime`, but I’d be very surprised if they didn’t work too. In any case, if your timestamp is always in UTC and always has the trailing `Z` for UTC, then I would consider `Instant` the most correct type for it in Java.

### Link

[jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8)

Comment: what you are doing is correct but I'm working under spring-boot which include out of the box configuration and looks like there is an issue when the message gets deserialized

Comment: I want some solution for spring-boot and spring-cloud

Comment: I used this with Spring Boot in my work. Used Spring boot for exchanging JSON with a RESTful web service and code like the above for converting JSON to and from my own object types. Sorry that I have no experience with Spring-cloud.